# Docker: port 0.0.0.0:4500->9090/tcp -- What is my host url?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Edit: Solved. It should be

```
services:
  web:
    ports:
       - "4500:4500"  # intead of "4500:9090"
```

Anyone know which url should I type to get the website deployment? The MySql server which is jdbc:mysql://192.168.99.100:3306/- it works fine.

But the web, tried 192.168.99.100:9090/category/all, 192.168.99.100:4500/category/all localhost:4500/actuator, localhost:9090/actuator, nothing works.

[image]
[image]

[image: Dockerfile]
Edit: After use curl from Nightt advice
[image]

Comment: you have to use port 4500

Comment: please give me the `docker run` command. Currently, your app is started at port 4500. So if you want to access web via web, try `http://localhost:4500`

Comment: @Nightt No docker run. The command is docker-compose up. http://192.168.99.100:4500/l or localhost:4500 not working. I edited my post. Dicker compose is above

Comment: @Vy Let try adding `EXPOSE 9090` into the end of dockerfile and rebuild the docker img. Dont forget make the app listen on port 9090 (you can check by `docker exec` into container and run `curl localhost:9090`).

Comment: `localhost:4500` should work if other parts is corect. What port and IP listening `TanKy.jar`? Is `192.168.99.100` container internal IP or Docker host IP? Try to understand [how docker networks work](https://dockerlabs.collabnix.com/networking/A2-bridge-networking.html).

Comment: @Nightt I added EXPOSE 9090 in Dockerfile and restart everything. t seems like of all 4 options, it can only curl localhost:4500/actuator . (I edit the image above.) But in my browser, it said Site cannot be reach, localhost refuse to connect. 
 In mysql, the url is 192.168.99.100:3306 and it is working. But the deploy is not. It so weird. It run succesfully in the springboot app though, connected to docker mysql container

Comment: @Nightt I changed everything 9090 to 4500 and it works at 192.168.99.100:4500 now. Thank you :))